Connection Between Circulation, Curl, and the Skew-Symmetric Part of the Jacobian Matrix
I am struggling to understand the connection between the following two formulas for the Curl of a vectorfield:

Integral Formula:
\begin{align}
   \lim_{A \to 0^+} \frac{1}{A} \oint_{\partial S} \mathbf{F} \cdot d\mathbf{r}
\end{align}
This seems to represent the averaged circulation of a vector field F around an infinitesimal surface A.

Skew-symmetric matrix:
\begin{align}   (J - J^T)
\end{align}
This represents the antisymmetric part of the Jacobi matrix as we linearlize the vectorfield. Why does this matrix give the same output as the integral above. In the lectures we talked about infinitesimal rotations, but those are described in my understanding by
\begin{align}
I+d\theta(J - J^T)
\end{align}


How exactly does the skew-symmetric part of the Jacobian matrix correspond to the curl and the interpretation of infinitesimal rotations? Could you provide a step-by-step explanation or intuition on how these concepts are connected?
Additionally, is there a way to see this equivalence explicitly in a derivation, or is it more of a conceptual bridge? Any examples or insights to clarify this connection would be appreciated!


As Ted Shifrin pointed out the circulaton $\oint_{\partial S}\mathbf{F}\cdot d\mathbf{r}$ is a scalar. So that
limit cannot be the curl vector $\nabla\times\mathbf{F}\,.$
However, I think we can say the following: By Stokes' theorem,
$$\tag1
\oint_{\partial S}\mathbf{F}\cdot d\mathbf{r}=\int_S(\nabla\times\mathbf F)\cdot\mathbf n\,dS\,.
$$
Now consider a surface $S$ that lies in the $xy$-plane and
shrinks to the point $\mathbf p\,.$
Since the unit normal of $S$ is always $\mathbf e_3$ it is not very hard to deduce that
$$\tag2
\lim_{|A|\to 0}\frac1{|A|}\int_S(\nabla\times\mathbf F)\cdot\mathbf n\,dS=
(\nabla\times\mathbf F)(\mathbf p)\cdot{\mathbf e}_3\,.
$$
In other words, that limit is the $z$-component  of the curl
$\nabla\times\mathbf F$ at $\mathbf p\,.$ Similar
considerations apply to the other components.

We know that the curl $\nabla\times\mathbf F$ is
$$
\pmatrix{
\partial_2F_3-\partial_3F_2\\
\partial_3F_1-\partial_1F_3\\
\partial_1F_2-\partial_2F_1}
$$
and that, for the Jacobian $J$ of $\mathbf F$ we have
$$
J-J^\top=\pmatrix{ 0 & \partial_2F_1-\partial_1F_2 & \partial_3F_1-\partial_1F_3\\ * & 0 & \partial_3F_2-\partial_2F_3\\
 * & * & 0}
$$
where I omitted the redundant entries due to anti-symmetry. (Note that there is no factor $1/2$.) The relationship between curl and that anti-symmetric part of $J$ is obviously the
one-to-one correspondence of every vector in $\mathbb R^3$ with
an anti-symmetric matrix
$$
\pmatrix{a\\b\\c}\longleftrightarrow\pmatrix{0&-c&b\\*&0&-a\\*&*&0}\,.
$$

Now to rotation matrices. Since $J-J^\top$ is skew-symmetric and $3\times 3$
its exponential
$$
R=\exp(J-J^\top)
$$
is a rotation matrix in $SO(3)$. By the Rodrigues formula the rotation axis is $\nabla\times\mathbf F$ and
the rotation angle is the length of $\nabla\times\mathbf F\,.$

When $J-J^\top$ is close to zero then $R$ is an "infinitesimal"
rotation
$$
R\approx I+J-J^\top\,.
$$
Example:
$$
\mathbf F=\pmatrix{-y\\x\\0}\,,\quad\nabla\times\mathbf F=\pmatrix{0\\0\\2}\,,
\quad J-J^\top=\pmatrix{0&-2&0\\2&0&0\\0&0&0}\,.
$$
From this post
$$
R=\pmatrix{\cos 2 & -\sin 2 & 0\\\sin 2&\cos 2 & 0\\0& 0&1}\,.
$$

Conversely, if $R(t)$ is a time-dependent rotation matrix which
describes a rotating rigid body. Then the space coordinates $\mathbf q$ of
every point of the body obey the equation
$$
\dot{\mathbf q}=\boldsymbol{\omega}\times\mathbf{q}
$$
where $\boldsymbol{\omega}$ (possibly time-dependent) is the
orbital angular velocity. This is related to the matrix $R(t)$
by
$$
\pmatrix{0&-\omega_3&\omega_2\\\omega_3&0&-\omega_1\\-\omega_2&\omega_1&0}=\dot RR^\top
$$
(see WP). In a rigid body $\boldsymbol{\omega}$ is the same for all
points and therefore depends only on on time. Therefore,
if $\mathbf{F}$ denotes the velocity field $\dot{\mathbf q}$
we have
$$
\mathbf{F}=\boldsymbol{\omega}\times\mathbf q=\boldsymbol{\omega}\times\pmatrix{x\\y\\z}
$$
and it is easily seen that
$$
\nabla\times\mathbf F=2\boldsymbol{\omega}\,.
$$




is wrong. A scalar does not a vector equal.


@TedShifrin you are right. Will correct this.
